# Transient/Recurrent Markov chain

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am currently studying the concept of recurrent and transient states and was wondering about the following: Is this concept dependent on the initial distribution?

Let me take this example: You can go from 1->2 and 2->1 with a positive probability. Also you can go from 3->4 and 4->3 with a positive probability. All other transition have zero probability. Now, if you start in 1 you can never go to 3, so the recurrence time of state 3 is infinite(you will never reach this state). Does this mean that 3 and 4 are transient?

Conversely, if I start in 3, the states 1 and 2 would be transient.

An alternative interpretation could be: Assuming that we were in state 3 once? How likely is it to come back? in that case 3,4 would be a recurrent states and 1,2 as well. So what is the right interpretation?

Furthermore, I would be interested in understanding the different meaning between a null-recurrent and a positive recurrent state? I mean, both correspond to recurrent states, so the markov chain will return to this state infinitely many times, so what is the difference in their interpretation?

Comment: you have two communicating classes

Comment: yes, i do!. is this a hint?

Comment: yes it is. Check the definition of a recurrent MC and what it has to do with the number of communicating classes.

Comment: ah, i see. the definition in my script sucks. so my second interpretation is right. correct?

Comment: if you run the MC 'for infinity' the probability of returning to state $j$ in a recurrent MC is one. If you have more than 1 communicating class it's obviously 0

Comment: @Alex don't understand this answer. It suggests that if you have two communicating classes, then you cannot have a recurrent one.

Comment: Grab a book: http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/

Comment: @Did yes, I am reading one, but I was very surprised about the Alex's answer. Cause I would have assumed that my two classes are closed and finite, so recurrent. But apparently, he thinks differently about this.

Comment: Alex suggested that you check the definition of a communicating class. Surely you did this, you might want to recall it.

Comment: @Did I don't understand: A communicating class is an equivalence class where you can always go from one state into any other(positive probability of transition $p^n_{A,B}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Right, now for the definitions of recurrent/transient states and of null recurrent/positive recurrent states.

Comment: @Did: The probability of the returning time being less than infinity if we start in a state $i$ to come back to this state $i$ is 1. (Which suggests that both classes are recurrent). The transient state means that this probability is less than one.

Comment: @Did I figured out that both null recurrent and positive recurrent states are recurrent states, so we always come back and this infinitely many times, the difference is: The expected time when we return for the first time is finite for the positive recurrent state, but infinite for the null recurrent.

Comment: So... what is left to solve?

Comment: nothing ( if I am correct ), I was just confused about Alex's last comment.